# How can I thread safely collect data from parallel processes into a single object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I have the following function for sending out multiple SMS:

```
BulkSMSSenderResult bulkResult = new BulkSMSSenderResult();

if (BulkRequest.Requests.Any()) {
    IEnumerable<(SMSSenderRequest, Task<Nito.Try<SMSSenderResult>>)> sendSmsTasks 
        = BulkRequest.Requests.Select(request => (request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request)));
    await Task.WhenAll(sendSmsTasks.Select(task => task.Item2));

    sendSmsTasks.ToList()
        .ForEach(task => {
            (SMSSenderRequest request, Task<Nito.Try<SMSSenderResult>> tryResult) = task;
            _ = tryResult.Result.Match<Either<ErrorMessage, SMSSenderResult>>(
                exception => new ErrorMessage(exception, request),
                value => value
            )
            .Match(
                result => bulkResult.Add(result),
                error => bulkResult.Add(error)
            );
        });
}

if (BulkRequest.BadRequests.Any()) {
    bulkResult.InvalidRequests = BulkRequest.BadRequests;
}

WriteResponseAsync(context, StatusCodes.Status207MultiStatus, bulkResult);
```

This works *almost* as intended, except it seems that all the SMS are being sent twice.

I think the problem may be with this line:

```
await Task.WhenAll(sendSmsTasks.Select(task => task.Item2));
```

My expectation was that this line should check that the SMSes have been sent, so that code which comes after would execute safely.

However, it seems either both this line and the code which follows are *both* causing `SendSingleSmsAsync(request)` to execute...  or something else (upon which I can't speculate) is causing the job to fire twice (and I'm sure `SendSingleSmsAsync(request)` itself is working properly).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on this statement:

```
IEnumerable<(SMSSenderRequest, Task<Nito.Try<SMSSenderResult>>)> sendSmsTasks 
                = BulkRequest.Requests.Select(request => (request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request)));
```

In `Select(request => (request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request))`, `Select` is a projection, and as such it is evaluated every time you enumerate that query.

In other words, you will have a **new** `(request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request))` pair in these places:

- `sendSmsTasks.Select(task => task.Item2)`, and
- `sendSmsTasks.ToList()`

Since `SendSingleSmsAsync` is a method invocation that returns a `Task`, you end up doing everything twice.

You can very easily fix the problem with just:

```
var sendSmsTasks = BulkRequest.Requests
    .Select(request => (request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request)))
    .ToArray();
```

But I would strongly suggest you to take a deep look at your code because it's growing very complex. Also, doing `.ToList().ForEach()` is a complete waste of resources (memory for the extra allocation, time for the extra loop), so change that to a simple `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

You have to think of Linq operations on enumerables more as setting up little mini-programs to be executed than actually going through and running them.

In your case, you set up the computation here:

```
IEnumerable<(SMSSenderRequest, Task<Nito.Try<SMSSenderResult>>)> sendSmsTasks 
                    = BulkRequest.Requests.Select(request => (request, SendSingleSmsAsync(request)))
```

But then you actually go through and execute it twice - here:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(sendSmsTasks.Select(task => task.Item2));
```

and here:

```cs
sendSmsTasks.ToList()
```

The fix would be to 'materialize' the enumerable as soon as possible, so that from that point on you're dealing with actual data instead of a chainable, lazy, would-be kind-of-thing.

Try sticking `.ToArray()` on the end of the enumerable's declaration.